# What is difference between Reduction, Simplification, and Cancellation?

Tags: terminology

I know basics, concepts and an idea of these terms. I am mathematician myself.

However, I'm struggling to understand the precise semantics of these *English* terms, and what exactly they imply in the Mathematics.

So, what is an exact, semantically definitive (mathematical) definition of *Reducing*, *Simplifying*, and *Cancelling*? how these terms differ in the Mathematics context?

I find them being used quite interchangeably, except *cancelling*, which is a bit more unambiguous, and it means to divide different parts of the expression by the same, non-zero divisor. Yet, quite often, even *cancelling* is swapped by two other terms mentioned above.

Any precise and definitive explanation, please?